# Break on debug message in GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb

Is it possible to have GDB break each time it receives a debug log message?

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you mean by "debug log" message, and what you mean by "it".

GDB itself normally does *not* receive any messages, unless something happens in the inferior (being debugged) process; such as inferior receiving `SIGSEGV`, or `SIGTRAP` due to executing a breakpoint instruction.